# How can I pass a data-id value to a ViewComponent

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core

I want to use a ViewComponent in a Modal dialog to edit some data, I can get the ViewComponent to show on screen, when I click the button and if I hard code a value it will retrieve the correct data.

```
@await Component.InvokeAsync("Contact", 2);
```

or
    @await Component.InvokeAsync("Contact", new { id=2 });

But what I can't see how to do is make the Id dependent upon which button I click. Ideally I'd like to just use data-id.
All the examples I've seen used fixed values.

Edit:

The ViewComponent is used in a ModalTagHelper, which is toggled on via an anchor tag, but I also have some jQuery that fires first.

```
$('.btnShow').on('click', function () {
    $('#hdnContactId').val($(this).data('id'));
    alert($('#hdnContactId').val());
});

<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-id="@Model.StudentContactId" data-target="#EditContact" class="btnShow btn btn-default">Edit</a>


<modal id="EditContact" title="Contact Details">
    <modal-body>
        @await Component.InvokeAsync("Contact", new { id=2 });
    </modal-body>
    <modal-footer>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
    </modal-footer>
</modal>
```

Comment: Cab you share how button click is invoking this code?

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I finally figured a way to do it.
I removed the @await etc from the modal section, so by default it gets no data.
Then in the Controller I added:

```
public IActionResult ContactViewComponent(int Id) {  
    return ViewComponent("Contact", Id);  
}
```

and changed my script to:

```
$('.btnShow').on('click', function (e) {
    $('#hdnContactId').val($(this).data('id'));
    var container = $(".modal-body");
    $.get("/Contact/ContactViewComponent?Id=" + $(this).data('id'), function (data) { container.html(data); });
});
```

and it now works :)